# Powershell - query all users who only belong to domain users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like an active directory query to list all users who only belong to "Domain Users" and no other groups.

I already tried the following query, but it showed all users with all groups they belong to:

```
Import-Module Activedirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName,memberof | % {
  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    UserName = $_.DisplayName
    Groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","
    }
} | Select UserName,Groups | Export-Csv C:\temp\report.csv -NTI
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for an empty `memberof`-property while `PrimaryGroup` is "*Domain Users*". No need to list the groups if you expect nothing.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "samaccountname -eq 'froflatest-sshf'" -Properties Memberof, PrimaryGroup, DisplayName, Description |
Where-Object { -not ($_.memberof) -and $_.PrimaryGroup -match 'Domain Users' } |
Select-Object SamAccountName, DisplayName, Description |
Export-CSV -Path "c:\report.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: How to put that into a .csv file with the description and username?

Comment: See updated answer with export. The question was how to query only those users, so I wanted to keep it clean and let you add it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Module Activedirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter "*" -Properties sAMAccountName,Description, Memberof, PrimaryGroup |
Where-Object { -not ($_.memberof) -and $_.PrimaryGroup -match 'Domain Users' } | Select sAMAccountName,Description | Export-Csv C:\temp\report.csv -NTI
```